# Use modified package file in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to use a modified version of one of a package's source files (a `.js` script for an htmlwidget in this case) in my shiny app, instead of the installed version. How do I do this?

Comment: Could you give an example? Its not possible to overwrite the file in the package directory?

Comment: I can do that and have it work locally, but when I deploy the app to shinyapps.io it installs the packages from CRAN (right?)